# Kafka Streams join using UnlimitedWindows

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have a topic which each message process an operation, and another topic which keep tracking of the grouped operations. Let's call them `operation` and `batchOperations`.

Every `operation` has the same key of `batchOperations`, and batch operations has the id of all `operations`.

When producing the messages, first I send synchronous all `operation` messages, then I send the `batchOperation` message.

If by any means the `batchOperation` is not produced, do not start to process the `operations`, because they will be orphan.

I was think to join this to topics using kafka streams to ensure that they will only execute if both messages are emitted. After all operation are executed (with success or not) I will send a tombstone to erase the StateStore and free memory.

But kafka only permits join two streams using timed window. Digging downI found that kafka has a `UnlimitedWindows`, however didn't find any resource on the internet about it and I am wondering if this would be the best approach for my problem.

Comment: Not 100% sure if I understand you question, however, the `UnlimitedWindows` is for aggregation only. In general, Kafka Streams supports stream-stream, stream-table, and table-table joins. Of those don't work for you, you could still implement a custom join using a `Processor`.

Comment: A table is basically an unlimited window, depued by key